# How to trigger a tx_news search using typolink

Tags: typo3, tx-news

We recently switched from tt_news to Georg Ringers News extension and I - as a novice typo3 coder - need help fixing some typoscript code that was used to trigger context specific searches using typolink.

The old snippet was

```
typolink.parameter = 649
typolink.useCacheHash = 1
typolink.additionalParams.current = 1
typolink.additionalParams.wrap = &tx_ttnews[swords]=|
```

The new parameter needs to be `&tx_news_pi1` but swords does not work. I can't find documentation or examples how the search value can be set. I searched the code itself and dumb tried my luck with `&tx_news_pi1[search]=|` but that just shows the default numerical typo3 error "Oops, an error occurred! Code: 2018020814150924e87636" if something cannot be rendered. BTW: The referenced search result page works fine if called using the search form.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to reformat your question a little. Please add the error you got to your question using the edit function. This increases your chance to get help and might make the error known to google for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grabbing through the code try `&tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][search][subject]=|`.
On the target list you need to allow overwriting of the demand in the plugin flexform!

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Thomas works for me even without the [overwriteDemand] using the search result page as target. Thx.

```
typolink.parameter = 649
typolink.useCacheHash = 1
typolink.additionalParams.current = 1
typolink.additionalParams.wrap = &tx_news_pi1[search][subject]=|
```

I really would like to know how this could be grabbed from the code. :-) It seems that I have to learn more about php and the underlying data structure - [search][subject] looks like a kind of array which I didn't expect for that type of parameter.

Comment: This is years of experience where to look. ;) You can learn that as well.